# How to handle errors in Next.js API routes?

Tags: next.js, error-handling

What's the best way to handle errors in Next.js API routes? Currently Next always redirects to my error pages (404/500), which in turn sends my Sentry error logging mad. Is there a way to prevent this? I feel like errors in API routes should just return a JSON message with status. I've tried to catch thrown errors and return the appropriate responses which work locally but in production it still redirects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I create a custom error class

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode) {
      super(message);
      this.statusCode = statusCode;
      //  captureStackTrace returns a string that reperesents the location of that particular error in the call. gives us a stack that helps us to find the location of that error in the code. this will help us to find the exact error in our code.
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
  }
```

Then to avoid writing `try/catch` block I write a custom function to handle async error:

```
const catchAsyncErrors = (func) => (req, res, next) =>
  // passing a controller function
  Promise.resolve(func(req, res, next)).catch(next);
```

Then a controller:

```
const getSingleItem = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  // in express we had req.params
  const item = await Item.findById(req.query.id);
  if (!item) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Item not found with this id", 404));
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    item,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the response with the `res.status`.

```
async function example(req, res) {

  switch (req.method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const {  data } = await foo();
        res.status(200).json({ ...data});

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(error.requestResult.statusCode).send(error.message);
      }
    default:
      res.status(405).end(); //Method Not Allowed
      break;
  }
}

export default example;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working for nextjs 13 app directory there are two way using fetch new Response and another using NextResponse.
[Video reference from codeCodegrepper](https://www.grepper.com/answers/696070/nextjs+api+error+response?ucard=1)

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
try{
  ........
   try code 
  .........
}catch(error){
  catch (error) {
    //Response given by fetch api where we have to stringify our object 
    // return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: "could not fetch group by" }), { status: 500 });
    
    //Here Nexjs simple our work by giving NextResponse
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Could not fetch group by" }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```